# Generic of function of (T, S), S inherits T

Tags: vb.net

I'll need to have a function that takes two different types :

- T (which has its own constraints)
- S must inherit T (or be T obviously)

Is this possible?

Tried:

```
 Public Sub MySub(Of t , s as Whatever(of T) )
```

Question might sound too short, but I don't see what more I can try...

[edited: I found out too late how dumb that question was. Sorry TT.TT ]

Comment: Could you a bit of context why you would require specifically S to be passed and not T?

Comment: MySub(Of T, S As T)

Comment: Why have you tagged C#?

Comment: @DavidG : C# and VB.NET are equivalent, if someone gives me the solution in C#, I get it in VB.NET. What happenned BTW : i wanted to accept the answer from InBetween, as it directly led to the same solution as Evk. I found it that way before seeing evk answer

Comment: @krzystof : I need to store the subclass in a variable. I need to define the variable as S otherwise , with only the parent class, I'll have a cast

Comment: That's not how this site works though. Next time please pick a single language and stick with it.

Comment: @DavidG OK then, i'll know for next time

Comment: @Pierre You might want to (re)think about your design as you should be able to work with the abstraction (See Liskov substitution principle) :)

Comment: @Kzrystof : I'd love to discuss this in private if it is possible. The point is that this principle only partially works in the mind of the compiler.
If T is icomparable(of T), and S inherits T, s is NOT icomparable (of S)

Comment: @Pierre No problem!

Comment: @Kzrystof : errrrrrr now I think that my question was probably dumb in fact... I'll check that after a good night of sleep -__-"

Comment: @Kzrystof : yeah I feel ashamed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void MySub<T, S>(T t, S s)
    where T: IFoo
    where S: T
{
    ....
}
```

But, if `S` is a `T`, are you sure you need an `S`? Maybe the following is enough:

```
public void MySub<T>(T t, T s)
    where T: IFoo
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: well I guess it was so easy I never thought of it... Thanks!

Comment: I'll need to be able to store a S  into a new variable without casting it into T.